# When training with pytorch, debugger hangs, even though running works fine

Tags: python, debugging, deep-learning, pytorch, pycharm

Trying to train with pytorch hangs in debug mode, but works in run mode.

```
    sampler_train = WeightedRandomSampler(
        sample_weights_train,
        num_samples=len(sample_weights_train),
        replacement=True
    )

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_set,
        sampler=sampler_train,
        batch_size=32,
        num_workers=2
    )


   for epoch in range(10): 
        for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
            model.train()
            print("something")
```

After placing a breakpoint on `model.train()`, then moving on to the next line, "something" is never printed in debug mode, but is printed in run mode in Pycharm.

How to debug my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I found the answer [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39489), which led to [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37366)

> Setting Gevent Compatible in Preferences | Build, Execution,
> Deployment | Python Debugger solves the issue.